# Create bitmap from specified screen area

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm trying to create a bitmap from a specific area on the screen. For example in the following image how could I capture the windowed area below and convert it into a bitmap?

[image]

I know you can use setDrawingCacheEnabled(true), but that captures the whole view, when all I want is an area within the view.

Comment: crop the bitmap you get by enabling drawing cache?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can actually use Android's `BitmapRegionDecoder.decodeRegion()` after you create an `InputStream` from your `Bitmap`.

You can pass a `Rect` object to the `decodeRegion` method like so:

```
BitmapRegionDecoder brd = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(inputStream, true);
Bitmap croppedBitmap = brd.decodeRegion(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom), null);
```

Cheers q:)