# screen shot of a specific screen area in android

Tags: android

I was trying to take screen shot of a specific area of a Android screen programatically, i can take screen shot of a particular view, but is there any way to capture a specific area of a screen or view. I was trying with Surface view and want to capture specific co-ordinates.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527620/create-bitmap-from-specified-screen-area

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way to capture a specific area of a screen or view

Capture something larger, then cut out the "specific area" into a separate `Bitmap`, probably using [one of the `createBitmap()` methods](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).